# find all vectors orthogonal to both:

Tags: linear-algebra

Find all vectors v = (x, y, z) orthogonal to both

$u_1$ = (2, -1, 3)
$u_2$ = (0, 0, 0)

I'm not sure how to get to the answer of s(1, 2, 0) + t(0, 3, 1). I know how to find a vector orthogonal to just 1, getting confused with the both part.

Comment: The zero vector is orthogonal to everything.

Answer (score 1):

What vectors are perpendicular to the zero vector? By definition al vectors z whose scalar product with the zero vector equals zero:

How do you chose $a,b,c$ s.t. $0a+0b+0c=0$?

Right, you can chose what you want!

So the question reads: find all vectors orthogonal to $(2,-1,3)$.

Does that help you? :)

Answer (score 0):

$x$ is orthogonal to $u_1$ and $u_2$ if and only if $\langle x, u_1\rangle = \langle x, u_2\rangle = 0$ if and only if $\begin{bmatrix}- u_1-\\ - u_2-\end{bmatrix} x = 0$ if and only if $x$ is in the kernel of $\begin{bmatrix}- u_1-\\ - u_2-\end{bmatrix}$

I trust you know how to calculate the kernel of $\begin{bmatrix}2&-1&3\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$ at this point if you are talking about orthogonality.